# make wants to know how to make target foo.cpp

Tags: c++, makefile

Thought I was following a simple prescription for makefiles found elsewhere on SO, but when I make using this makefile, it complains:

make: *** No rule to make target 'CI_Metadata.cpp', needed by 'CI_Metadata.o'.  Stop.

```
OTHER_INCLUDES+=-I${PWD}/include -I/usr/local/include

all: CI_Metadata.o ConnectMxctl.o Block.o test_block.o
        g++ -o tester CI_Metadata.o ConnectMxctl.o Block.o test_block.o

ConnectMxctl.o: ConnectMxctl.cpp ConnectMxctl.h
        g++ -c $(OTHER_INCLUDES) ConnectMxctl.cpp

CI_Metadata.o: CI_Metadata.cpp CI_Metadata.h
        g++ -c $(OTHER_INCLUDES) CI_Metadata.cpp

Block.o: Block.cpp Block.h
        g++ -c $(OTHER_INCLUDES) Block.cpp

test_block.o: test_block.cpp
        g++ -c $(OTHER_INCLUDES) test_block.cpp
```

Comment: Usually means the file is missing.

Comment: Is that file *definitely* in the directory that you're running Make from?

Comment: No.  It's running in a directory that contains a ./c directory and an ./include directory.  (As per the setup at work)  How on earth do I express that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the directive `vpath` in such situations with GNU make. It significantly reduces the complexity compared to Makefiles without `vpath`. Here is a working example:

```
vpath %.cpp c
vpath %.h include

CPPFLAGS = -Iinclude

objs = CI_Metadata.o ConnectMxctl.o Block.o

tester: test_block.o $(objs)
        $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(objs): %.o: %.cpp %.h
```

However, this Makefile is still completely broken. The dependencies between the `.cpp` file and the corresponding `.h` file are defined, but all other include dependencies are missing. It can be solved using the compiler to generate the dependencies (e.g. with the option `-MM`), but it makes the Makefile quite complex.

If you do not have to use make, I strongly recommend using a modern build tool. Because you are developing with C++, I recommend using [boost-build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/) (aka *bjam*). The `Jamroot` for the above `Makefile` looks as follows:

```
exe tester : [ glob c/*.cpp ] : <include>include ;
```